# Angular Application's first page very slowly to load

Tags: javascript, angular

I'am hosting my .Net Core / Angular application.
When I visit the url of my application the first page makes more than 90 seconds to load. I found that these files are very Big (15MB): styles. J's, scripts. J's, main. J's, vendor. J's, pollyfills. J's.
So I used this website to minifier the js code https://jscompress.com/
Now my application is faster, but I think that it can be faster.
Do you have any idea please ?[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BisP.png)

Comment: First, compile with the `--prod` flag (`ng build --prod`), the code will be much smaller and faster. Then, use lazy loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you have your application structured, but if possible you could break things up into [lazy loaded modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

I would check into this article, which mentions a variety of possible things to look into when trying to improve load times: https://medium.com/khojchakra/reduce-initial-load-time-of-angular-application-9b9ed4a6bfc9

Also try to serve your application AOT when you go to actually serve it for production if you are not already. This could speed things up quite a bit; but not during local development. the app reload times are quite depressing when making code changes with aot enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build with ng AOT option:
ng build --aot --build-optimizer.
You can find out more here https://angular.io/cli/build
With this your app should load faster

Comment: Yeah or just `--prod` that enables all optimizations at once

Answer (score 0):

Always use latest versions of angular. Do code splitting. Lazy loading the modules reduces your initial bundle size. Remove unused imports. Try to avoid bloated third party libraries. Proper segregation of functionalities into separate modules.

Advanced: AFter doing all of the above, if you still want to reduce your bundle size. Try Using bazel for build process. https://blog.mgechev.com/2018/11/19/introduction-bazel-typescript-tutorial/

More Advanced: Still you want to reduce your bundle size. Wait for Angular Ivy(public release).

Comment: Ivy has been the default engine since Angular 9